# HTTP call with a custom header(cookie)

Tags: c#, http, windows-8, header, httpcookie

As I am a C# newbie, it would be really helpful if I could get some support here. I have an Android phone and an application from Android phone should be usable in Windows 8 phone as well. The problem is not with the working of functionalities but the problem is with the transition, it requires just a plugin say a HTTP call with a custom header named Cookie and if I get this, then transition should be quite easier. Can any of you help please?

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate your question, you would like access to the Hypertext Transfer Protocol Header information.  Microsoft has really simplified access to such information:

```
var content = request.Headers["cookie"];
```

To break it down:

- `var` : Will dynamically assign the type.
- `content` : Our variable name for our `object` in this instance.
- `request` : Represents our `WebRequest`
- `Headers` : Is the available `header` content, through our `HttpContext`.
- `["cookie"]` : Is accessing our header collection, with the name.

You can find more information on headers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.header(v=vs.110).aspx).  I believe the Microsoft Developer Network is currently down for maintenance, so you may have to check in awhile.

A full example would be:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("url") as HttpWebRequest;
var response = request.GetWebResponse();
var header = response.Headers["cookie"];
```

Hopefully this points you in the proper direction.

Comment: Thank you Greg! But this is for accessing the headers in the RESPONSE, but now we need to send it in the REQUEST.

Comment: @dmurali The example does exactly that at the bottom.